# EZ-1 Super Cruiser Weight limit

Tags: recumbent

I am trying to find out what the weight limit is on the EZ-1 Super Cruiser.  I have found a used one in great condition, but I am 319 pounds, so do not know if it would be a good option or not.

Comment: Have you looked at the manual or e-mailed the manufacturer?

Comment: Normally on a standard bike with no suspension the weigh limit is determined by the tires and wheels.  The frame of a recumbent, however, is placed under considerably more stress when heavily loaded than is a standard "diamond" frame.  But still the main thing to be concerned about is the wheels, and having them tuned up, replacing tires if they are worn or showing age, would be the most important thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your talking about the older Sun EZ-1 recumbent, the weight limit is 300lbs. You would probably be alright as most weight limit are a "lawyer number" meaning that is not the maximum capacity but for legal reasons they set it at that.

If you do get it i would recommend replacing the wheels on it at some point as the ones that come on it are so-so. And a heavier duty set of double wall rims and decent spokes would hold up a lot better over time if you'll be using it a lot. The wheels that come on them are Weinmann 519's which are a generic single wall rim.

The good thing is most the parts are very similar so if you need something as a replacement more than likely they are still being produced and available.

The company has sense changed it's name for recumbents to Sun Seeker, and is the house brand of J&B Importers a national parts distributor who also owns Origin8. The newest owners manual for the EZ-1 Classic (very similar) can be found [here](http://www.jbimporters.com/web/links/SunSeekerManualMain.pdf)

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it.  I looked through the manual but did not see anything on weight capacity.  I noticed the wheels seemed a bit small.  I was thinking if I do get it to replace the wheels and get a 20 inch wheel on the front also.  I would be riding around the city and on a paved rail trail...possibly commute to work, which is about 15 miles or so.  Trying to figure out if I really want to get the EZ1 or if I should go with a schwinn hardtail or maybe even a giant or trek hard tail.  The EZ1 is about $200, which I think is a good price.  It looks great in the pictures.

Comment: If you were to switch to a 20" in the front it would require a new fork as well. Which would bump the cost up, obvious, but something to consider. Long distance comfort of a recumbent is hard to beat for sure, you may also look at "tadpole" style where they have two wheels in the front and one in the back. They tend to have a more relaxed laid back posture and are an absolute hoot to tool around on. And 200 is a good deal depending on age and condition, brand new the newer models go for $1000 MSRP.